# TypeError: (0 , _stylis.compile) is not a function antd jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, antd

I get the following error when running tests TypeError: (0 , _stylis.compile) is not a function. This is happening when trying to render a component like so: Am I missing a config setting somewhere or are there versioning issues?

```
    test('testing', () => {
      render(<Test />)
    })



"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.12",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",   
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"

"@ant-design/icons": "^4.4.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-components": "^2.3.41",

"antd": "^5.0.4",

stack trace:
  at normalizeStyle (node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/hooks/useStyleRegister.js:38:63)
      at node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/hooks/useStyleRegister.js:245:22
      at node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/hooks/useGlobalCache.js:35:37
      at Entity.update (node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/Cache.js:25:23)
      at node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/hooks/useGlobalCache.js:23:17
```